# INVALID_ARGUMENT_TYPE : Missing field [TableEnumOrId] on trigger create

Tags: apex, trigger, tooling-api

I am using "ToolingAPI" to create a trigger dynamically , but I received this error:

> "INVALID_ARGUMENT_TYPE : Missing field [TableEnumOrId] on trigger create"

I am using this code:

```
ToolingAPI toolingAPI = new ToolingAPI();
toolingAPI.ApexTrigger newTrigger = new ToolingAPI.ApexTrigger();
newTrigger.Name = 'HelloWorld77';
newTrigger.Body = 'trigger HelloWorld77 on Account (before insert) {}';
```

and when I added this line :

```
newTrigger.tableEnumOrId = 'Account';
```

I received an another error:

> System.StringException: Invalid id: Account

The tooling api wrapper used here is provided on [Github](https://github.com/afawcett/apex-umlcanvas/blob/master/src/classes/ToolingAPI.cls).

Comment: *"System.StringException: Invalid id: Account"* indicates that you are trying to assign a string to an ID typed property. The ToolingAPI clearly indicates *"Public Id tableEnumOrId;"*, line 566.

Comment: Yes , but according to the error **Missing field** , I have to add **tableEnumOrId** for example in my case I am creating a trigger for Account so I have to add it into the variable **tableEnumOrId ** , how can i do it ? thank

Comment: Maybe you should log an issue in GitHub.

Comment: I also did it but it is a very interesting question , for example we can use ToolingApi to create a class and it is very easy , but there is not a simple example about the creation of a trigger from apex code.

Comment: @Raphym yes please post this as an issue on the GitHub repo, https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi/blob/apex-toolingapi-rest/src/classes/ToolingAPI.cls thanks

Comment: Also there are some examples here, https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi/blob/apex-toolingapi-rest/src/classes/ToolingAPIDemo.cls (this uses the REST wrapper version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right , thank you very much !

*In conclusion the solution is:*

**In the class **ToolingAPI.cls** change two things :**

1. `public Id tableEnumOrId; to public String tableEnumOrId;`
2. `jsonGen.writeIdField('tableEnumOrId', tableEnumOrId); to                    jsonGen.writeStringField('tableEnumOrId', tableEnumOrId);`

And of course you can know use it here :

```
    ToolingAPI toolingAPI = new ToolingAPI();
    toolingAPI.ApexTrigger newTrigger = new ToolingAPI.ApexTrigger();
    newTrigger.Name = 'HelloWorld77';
    newTrigger.Body = 'trigger HelloWorld77 on Account (before insert) {}';
    newTrigger.tableEnumOrId='Account';
    toolingAPI.createSObject(newTrigger);
```

I advise you to use the Andrew API from here: 
https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi/tree/apex-toolingapi-rest

**Thank you all for your cooperation**

***Raphael***

Answer (score 4):

The problem is likely related the Tooling API wrapper you are using.

From the [source for ApexTrigger](https://github.com/afawcett/apex-umlcanvas/blob/master/src/classes/ToolingAPI.cls#L566):

```
public class ApexTrigger extends SObject_x implements ISerialize {
    //...
    public Id         tableEnumOrId;
    //...
}
```

Note how that is an Id rather than string type. It needs to be a string so in can specify either the TableEnum or the Id.

From the [Docs on TableEnumOrId](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apextrigger.htm):

> **Type**
>   Restricted picklist
>   **Description**
>   The enum (for example, Account) or ID of the object this field is on.

---

I was able to create a new ApexTrigger specifying just the `Name`, `Body`, and `TableEnumOrId` fields.

[image: Creating an Apex Trigger directly with the Tooling API]

Comment: Nice spot, yes changing it to String should resolve this issue. The formal location of the REST based wrapper is here, https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi/blob/apex-toolingapi-rest/src/classes/ToolingAPI.cls.